# Default Parameter based on another fields value - Crystal Reports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

Is there any way to set a default parameter value in a Crystal report based on another fields value.

Example:

I have orderrel.plant and warehousecode.plant. I have a parameter for warehousecode.plant, but would like the default vaule for that parameter to be based off of orderrel.plant's value. Basically, orderrel.plant is the plant that the sales order should be shipped from, but I want to be able able to chose to check anothers plant's inventory in case it can be shipped from there.  The defaulting the parameter will help the user know which plant it is supposed to ship from, without having to go look at the sales order.

Many thanks in advance.

-- Update

Here is the query:

```
    SELECT     orderhed.ordernum, orderdtl.orderline, orderrel.orderrelnum, orderhed.custnum, orderhed.requestdate AS hedrequestdate, orderhed.orderdate AS hedorderdate, 
                  orderdtl.partnum, orderdtl.requestdate AS dtlrequestdate, orderrel.reqdate AS relreqdate, orderrel.needbydate AS relneedbydate, orderrel.ourreqqty, 
                  orderrel.plant AS releaseplant, partwhse.plant, partwhse.warehousecode, partwhse.allocqty, partwhse.onhandqty, part.partdescription
    FROM         part RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  orderdtl ON part.company = orderdtl.company AND part.partnum = orderdtl.partnum RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  orderhed ON orderdtl.company = orderhed.company AND orderdtl.ordernum = orderhed.ordernum LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  orderrel ON orderdtl.company = orderrel.company AND orderdtl.ordernum = orderrel.ordernum AND orderdtl.orderline = orderrel.orderline LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  partwhse ON orderdtl.company = partwhse.company AND orderdtl.partnum = partwhse.partnum
    WHERE     (orderhed.ordernum = @p_ordernum) AND (orderhed.company = 'lot')
    ORDER BY orderhed.ordernum, orderdtl.orderline, orderrel.orderrelnum
```

To explain a little more in detail... Every sales order release has a plant that the order will be fulfilled from (orderrel.plant).   I am making a report that will look at a specified sales order, and give the on hand/allocated qty's in our warehouses in certain plants.  I want the user to be able to run the report, but instead of it just looking at the order releases plant for on hand values, to be able to look at other plants for inventory, to see if/where we could fulfill the order from.  The partwhse.plant (incorrectly called warehouse.plant previously) is what plant field I need to use to define what plant I want to look at for stock on hand values.  This is the field that I have the parameter on.  I want it to default to the orderrel.plant's value, so that without having to look up the order, the user will know that yes I am looking at the order releases plant for inventory.

I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: This is a little confusing to me. Can you post the query (including selection criteria)?

Comment: A parameter's default value can only be set in the parameter itself.  If you can describe the need a little more clearly, we might be able to offer other approaches.